# Validating empty Email input for form field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

**Html :**

```
<input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter an Email ID" name="Email" id="Email" pattern="((\w+\.)*\w+)@(\w+\.)+(com|kr|net|us|info|biz)" required="required">
```

**Script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkStatus() {
        var productcode = $("#Code").val();
        var productEmail = $("#Email").val();
        alert("email is== " + Email)

        if (!document.getElementById("Email").checkValidity()) {
            alert("Please Enter Valid Email Id");
            return false;

        } else {
            callMeIfValid();
        }

        document.getElementById('Email').value = '';    
    }

    function callMeIfValid() {    
        alert("valid input");    
    }
</script>
```

In the above code i am able to validate whether the email id given by user is valid or not based on the `regex` pattern inside input tag.But i Want to perform `validation` when the user submits an empty field(*without any email input*).
Is there any possibility?any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify.  Is an email field *valid* for your purposes, or invalid?

Comment: @Malvolio sorry i did not get you... i want to validate when user submits with empty field then its getting submitted..

Comment: Check the `required` attribute and html5's type `email`.

Comment: guys why you are unvoting my question? my question is right and also got solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

JS

```
if(document.getElementById("Email").value=='')
{
  alert("Please Enter Email ID");
  return false;    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/j0ba5h3u/)

Note: HTML5 `required` attribute may not work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check whther user has entered any text or value using .val(), then check for valid or invalid input.

Comment: Try using this before you check for valid/invalid email....if(document.getElementById('Email').value=='')
{
    alert("Please enter Email Id");
    return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

where there is your < form > tag in html add this attribute

example:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" bla bla bla>  // put onsubmit in your form tag
```

and then write this jquery function

```
function validate(){
    if($("#Email").val()=='')
    {
        alert("Please Enter Email ID");
        return false;    
    }
 }
```